# /admin/recently-self-deleted is not showing a self-deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, deleted-questions, self-delete

I'm a moderator on [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/). I recently was surprised to find a question I had ‘helped with’ vanish without a trace from the site (including any references to my actions on it). Now, of course, questions can be deleted, but deletions are of interest to moderators, right?

As part of my search, I found the `/admin/recently-self-deleted` page and went there. *The question was not listed* even though, afterward, I determined that it had been self-deleted (at the time) *two hours ago*. It is now days since the deletion and the question is still not showing up, even though other questions have. This seems like a bug.

For any moderators/SE staff wishing to investigate: [this is the question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/) and [here's the page not showing it](https://ham.stackexchange.com/admin/recently-self-deleted).

The question has no votes, no answers, and was deleted one day after it was posted.

---

[A similar problem has been reported on another site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276108/moderator-recently-self-deleted-posts-list-is-missing-some-questions)

Comment: If you click on the question link, does it give a 404 page or can you see the deleted question?

Comment: @wythagoras I can see the deleted question.

Comment: Then it is indeed very weird. If you couldn't see the deleted question, it could be a hard-deleted question, i.e. a question that was removed form the database.

Comment: Are those posts present now, or [have we encountered the same bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276108/moderator-recently-self-deleted-posts-list-is-missing-some-questions)?

Comment: @Gilles I just checked back, and more recently deleted posts have shown up but that particular one has not. Updated.

Comment: @Gilles Your edit went too far. The question on my site is not answered.

Comment: @Kevin does the self deleted question have any answers? If so, you should keep the previous title, since the bug is specific to questions with answers

Comment: @ShadowWizard It has zero answers, I meant.

Comment: hmm... and what is the question score? /cc @Gilles

Comment: @ShadowWizard Updated.

Comment: @KevinReid Oh, sorry, I'd understood “helped with” to mean “answered”. So it still may or may not be the same bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard For the three examples I listed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276108/moderator-recently-self-deleted-posts-list-is-missing-some-questions, the question scores are -1 (+1/-2), 1 (+1/0) and 0 (0/0). The answer scores are always 0 (0/0).

Comment: @Gilles weird, let's hope the team will figure this out...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently there's a requirement that posts must be visible on the site for more than a day in order to show up in that list.

This *sort* of makes sense in that showing every post that was created mistakenly and immediately removed would just noisy up the list...

...But a day is kind of a long time for a post to be visible on most sites. Not to mention confusing for folks like you when, after seeing *and working on* such a post, it disappears without a trace.

I'd recommend reducing this restriction to something small like 10 minutes, or dropping it entirely.

**2019-02-04:** After failing to find any documented reason for this, I've dropped the restriction entirely; this list should now contain the last 1000 author-deleted posts. Also fixed an unrelated bug wherein posts would previously be included if they'd *ever* been self-deleted, even if they were later undeleted and then deleted again by someone else.

Comment: I've just come across this myself and can think of at least 3-4 posts in the last weekend that fail to show up on the recently self deleted for this reason. This needs to be implemented please!

Comment: [This is still a problem](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/another-self-deleted-question). Any estimate on when it's going to be fixed? 6–8 years? 6–8 decades? 6–8 aeons? Or even better, remove this misfeature of allowing question deletion when there is an answer?

Comment: Today, @Gilles.

Comment: Thank you! It's still far from ideal, because there's no way to filter it, but at least now the posts do show up, so it's “just” a matter of finding the ones we want (in my case, usually, what I'm looking for is the answered ones).

Comment: Something like [is:question deleted:1 answers:1 isanswered:0 closed:0](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20deleted%3a1%20answers%3a1%20isanswered%3a0%20closed%3a0) probably gets closer to what you want then, @Gilles

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed a lot more useful.