# Moderator “Recently Self-Deleted Posts” list is missing some questions

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, deleted-questions, recently-deleted

I was investigating self-deleted questions and noticed that several are missing from the [Recently Self-Deleted Posts](https://cs.stackexchange.com/admin/recently-self-deleted) list: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52567/determining-length-of-a-walk-in-nfa-with-lambda-transitions, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52521/calculating-time-complexity, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/spanning-forest

One thing they have in common is that they are all questions that have a zero-score answer that was deleted together with the question. I don't know whether that's the source of the bug or just an observation bias (deletion of zero-score answers through question deletion is what I was investigating in the first place).

The deletions are weeks old so it's not just caching.

(Note: this is a moderator tool, links are ♦ only.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274642/215468

Comment: @Undo Maybe — mine is definitely not just staleness but maybe Kevin's problem wasn't staleness either.