# Show more posts on the "Recently Self Deleted" admin page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, self-delete

I've been futilely searching for a couple of questions that I *know* were posted on Interpersonal Skills over the weekend - one just this morning.

In my search I discovered that we don't show self-deleted posts on the "Recently Deleted" posts list on the Tools page but that we do have the nice /admin/recently-self-deleted page that does... except [according to this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276166/284336), we only show these posts if they were on the site for a minimum of 24 hours.

> Apparently there's a requirement that posts must be visible on the site for more than a day in order to show up in that list.
>
> This sort of makes sense in that showing every post that was created mistakenly and immediately removed would just noisy up the list...
>
> ...But a day is kind of a long time for a post to be visible on most sites. Not to mention confusing for folks like you when, after seeing and working on such a post, it disappears without a trace.
>
> I'd recommend reducing this restriction to something small like 10 minutes, or dropping it entirely.

This means that, in some cases, there may be no record of a question for any mod to find except for, possibly, a chat feed. Otherwise, the only way to find the post is by knowing the username and checking their profile page.

As recommended in Shog's answer, could we please lower the time limit for this to something less than a day. I'm good with 10 minutes but if someone has a strong argument for something longer, feel free to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, the list includes the last 1000 self-deleted posts, regardless of how soon after being posted they were deleted.

Answer (score 6):

If you're ok with seeing *all* deleted posts (not just self-deleted ones), as a moderator you can now use site search.  For example, the following search returns all posts that were deleted within the last two days:

> created:2d.. deleted:yes

For more search tricks (including date ranges and score ranges), visit [$SITENAME/help/searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).